# In Java, is String s = new String() any use at all?

Tags: java, string, constructor, arguments

Since Strings are immutable in Java, why would I want to use the argument-less String constructor and create an object?

How is the variable `s` useful to me after I do:

```
String s = new String();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new String()` is an empty string. This could be a return value from a method, for example, if you don't have anything more interesting to return. Using the literal `""` is probably better because the literal empty string value will already be interned.

Answer (score 4):

It is an empty string, equivalent to `""`. From the javadoc:

> Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents an empty character sequence. Note that use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.

EDIT:

Poor choice of use of the word *equivalent*. To clarify all of the following are `true`:

```
"" == ""
"" != new String()
"".equals(new String())
```

Comment: "equivalent" ... but "identical"? `new String() == ""`?

Comment: @pst `new String() == ""` will be false. They don't represent the same Object as the String Object doesn't come from the intern pool.

Answer (score 3):

> Since strings are immutable in Java, why would I want to use the argument less String constructor and create an object?

The only reason would be if you *wanted* to create a String that was `equal` to `""` but not identical to it.  And even then it is more likely that you would be calling `new String(str)` where `str` refered to an empty string.

The real reason that the constructor is provided at all is not entirely clear.  However it does no harm, and there may have been some reason to have it in the beginning (before Java was called Java).

Comment: Interesting fact: .NET does not have this form (no-arg String constructor)

Comment: @pst - only interesting if you think this an interesting question.  My view is that the presence (or not) of a mostly useless method / constructor is irrelevant from a practical perspective.

Comment: @StephenC: I find useless methods or constructors distracting. When I see a new API I want it to be as simple as possible. Useless methods make me read more documentation, and I have to decide *not* to use them.